# Can JavaScript make outbound TCP connection over specific local port?

Tags: javascript, networking

Is there a way for JavaScript to query the local port that is used to connect to a server? Also, can I connect to a server by specifying a local port number?

The anology in Java would be

```
Socket socket = new Socket(0);
int localPort = socket.getLocalPort();
```

I think there would be security concerns with letting javascript access system resources. Just want to make sure if there is a way. 
If this is not possible in javascript, is there any other way to make a outbound TCP connection over a specific port?

Comment: Is it possible using websockets? How about a regular http request over tcp? Want to know if this is even possible with current browser technology.

Comment: Regular http request to another port (12345) would be an Ajax request to http://myserver:12345/index.html. I don't think that's going to cause a security problem. Available in browsers since 1999 :)

Comment: 12345 would be the port on the remote server. I am talking about the local port. If I make a http request to google.com my browser will use a local port > 1024. So the socket may be localhost:3456 -> google.com:80. Is there a way to query/bind to port 3456?